# NoMethodError - undefined method for a nested form from a join table using devise registration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, join, nomethoderror

I'm following [this tutorial](http://kakimotonline.com/2014/03/30/extending-devise-registrations-controller/) on how to nest other Models in my Devise registration form. I'm getting an error in my New controller:

'NoMethodError in Users::RegistrationsController#new  undefined method `languages_user=' for #'.

Languages_Users is a join table, and I'm wondering if this is the reason it isn't working, but I don't understand what the solution is. I want to add 2 different records of Languages_Users when the user signs up.

Models:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :role

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :location, :nationality, :bio

  before_save :assign_role

  def assign_role
    self.role = Role.find_by name: "user" if self.role.nil?
  end

  has_many :languages_users
    has_many :languages, :through => :languages_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :languages_users
```

Language.rb

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :languages_users
    has_many :users, :through => :languages_users
end
```

Langauges_user.rb

```
class LanguagesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :language

    validates_presence_of :user_id, :language_id, :level 
    validates :user_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :language_id, :message => 'can only delcare each language once. Please change the level of the language in Manage Languages.'}

end
```

Controllers:

registrations_controller.rb

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    build_resource({})
     self.resource.languages_user = LanguagesUser.new[sign_up_params]
    respond_with self.resource
  end
 def create
    @user_id = current_user.id
    super
 end

 def sign_up_params
    allow = [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, [languages_user_attributes: [:language_id, :user_id, :level]]]
  end
end
```

Relevant sections of User's new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
   <%= f.fields_for :langauges_user do |lu| %>
      <%#= lu.text_field :language_id %>
      <%= lu.collection_select(:language_id, Language.order('language ASC').all, :id, :language) %><br>
      <%= lu.hidden_field languages_user[level], value: 1 %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
 <% end %>
```

Relevant routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :languages_users
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  resources :users
    get 'languages_users/:id/sign_up', to: 'languages_users#sign_up', as: 'sign_up'

 end
```

I'm still learning - so please let me know if you need to see anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the first line of the error in full? You mention the error is occurring in "New controller" but I guess that's a typo. Also would be good to know your model structure, particularly associations: you mention `languages_users` is a join table, but in your code it also appears to be a model in its own right.

Comment: Sorry about that - I was trying not to overwhelm my post. I will post the full error and my schema. Anything else that would be helpful?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. No need for the schema - just need the associations of your three(?) models. If you're worried about wall of text, the full error suggests that `LanguagesUsersController` isn't involved, you can also take that out.

Comment: Got it - Thank you for the feedback. I made those adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that up to speed on Devise as I only recently started using it myself, but if I understand correctly it's not a Devise related problem - just harder to get a fix on because of Devise's `self.resource` abstraction.

You've deviated from your tutorial in an important respect: in the tutorial a `User` creates a `Company`, *but* the `Company` `has_many :users`. In your case the `User` creates a `LanguagesUser`, but here, the `User` `has_many :languages_users`. This means new syntax. This line, that's causing your error currently:

```
self.resource.languages_user = LanguagesUser.new[sign_up_params]
```

Needs to be along the lines of:

```
self.resource.languages_users.build(sign_up_params) #but see below re sign_up_params
```

Or if you want to save the associated resource right off the bat (I assume not, since you're not at the moment), you can use `create` or `create!` instead of `build`.

#### Aside

You may run into different trouble with your `sign_up_params` method, which also appears to have deviated from the tutorial - it doesn't actually use the `allow` array to whitelist any params, at least as written in your question. In any case, note they didn't use it when instantiating the `Company`, so it may not be fit for purpose when building your `LanguagesUser`, either.

A simple call to `sign_up_params[:languages_user_attributes]` should get you over the line, once you've fixed the `sign_up_params` method. Or you can set the nested object up with its own params whitelist.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me mess around with that and see

Comment: I'm confused about what you're suggesting for the params. Would it be:
`def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, [languages_user_attributes: [:language_id, :user_id, :level]])
  end`

Comment: @gwalshington Almost - I think it needs to be `params.require(:user).permit(:email, ..., languages_user_attributes: [:language_id, ...])`. And then if you run `self.resource.languages_users.build(sign_up_params[:languages_user_attributes])` it ought to work.

Comment: I tried that earlier as well, but it says 'param is missing or the value is empty: user'

Comment: @gwalshington `sign_up_params` requires the key `:user` to be present and is throwing an error because it isn't. You're best off inspecting your params with a `puts` in the controller, or a debugging tool, like pry. You appear to have some issues with your view that could be related, such as this typo: `<%= f.fields_for :langauges_user do |lu| %>`. However, we're onto new questions now. If my answer resolved your original issue please accept it!

Comment: Hey Kimball, I'm not sure if you answered the whole question, but the current error. I'm going to accept and repost as the entire issue, and if you have time it would be great to get some further explanation of the entire problem. Thanks!!